# How to resize the UIWebView content size on orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My application has a UIWebView which consists of an UIImageView as its subview, when i change the orientation of the device, the image in UIWebView is not affected and it remains in the same position as before. So is there a way to fix this issue. i want the image to automatically allign to its respective orientation.

Comment: Are you building the view from a xib or code?

Answer (score 0):

How about use "Size Inspector". Set as below, the image view will move to new position.

[image: ss]

Can you see what I have done in this picture? I removed all red lines around square so that the view moves to keep ratio of distance to edge of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the autoresizingMask which defines how the view behaves if the superviews bounds changes. In Xcode you can do it in the Interface Builder/Size Inspector.